Getting error by using lookup when resource is not exist
trying to do this:
{{- define "pos.mode" -}}
{{- $resource := lookup "monitoring.coreos.com/v1" "Prometheus" "cattle-monitoring-system" "rancher-monitoring-prometheus" | default (dict) -}}
{{- if and (has "eks" .Values.meta.val) (not (empty $resource)) }}
  desh
{{- else }}
  sesh
{{- end }}
{{- end }}

getting this error:
executing "pos.mode" at <lookup "monitoring.coreos.com/v1" "Prometheus" "cattle-monitoring-system" "rancher-monitoring-prometheus">: error calling lookup: unable to get apiresource from unstructured: monitoring.coreos.com/v1, Kind=Prometheus: the server could not find the requested resource

whats the issue with lookup?

Does your cluster actually have the prometheus-operator CustomResourceDefinitions installed?  You might need check with .Capabilities first.  You also might just make this directly configurable via a Helm value, rather than giving different results via lookup based on what might be installed in the cluster.

Cluster does not have the crd that's why I am getting this error. I know this issue but how can I resolve this? I need to check these resources.

If you're getting this error because a custom resource type isn't installed in the cluster, you can check first using the .Capabilities object.  Note that in some older versions of Go, the text/template language and function was a plain function and was not short-circuiting (it evaluated all arguments even if the first one was false); the formulation here requires at least Helm 3.10.0 (built with Go 1.18).
{{- $resource := and (.Capabilities.APIVersions.Has "monitoring.coreos.com/v1") (lookup "monitoring.coreos.com/v1" "Prometheus" "cattle-monitoring-system" "rancher-monitoring-prometheus") }}
{{- if and (has "eks" .Values.meta.val) (not $resource)) }}
  desh
{{- else }}
  sesh
{{- end }}

In the first line, we do the .Capabilities.APIVersions.Has check before calling lookup, which avoids this error.  Now $resource can be false (if the capabilities check fails), an empty dictionary (if the CRD is installed but the object doesn't exist), or a populated dictionary.  Both of the failing cases will be considered "falsey" for the call to not in the second conditional.  (We neither need to provide an empty dictionary as a default nor to specifically check for an empty value.)
